# How to diff before each commit without going into interactive mode?

Tags: bash, git, diff, commit

Say you do git status and you get back a list of files which you want to check one by one and then commit them one by one.

Or you do a git diff on a directory and want to go and commit directly after your inspection. How to do that with a simple trick?

Comment: This is kind of what `git add -i` is for. It's the interactive mode of git add that let's you work file-by-file and hunk-by-hunk, showing you the difference at each step.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

UPDATE 2020:

After fiddling around I decided to install and use `ydiff`.

Doing `ydiff -s` shows a diff side by side in the terminal.

No brainer check it out here and don't mind my old answer:

https://github.com/ymattw/ydiff

---

[ OLD
]

Git diff before your commit?

Simple solution thinking outside of the box:

Stick this in your .bashrc or .zshrc:

`gdiffy() { git diff $1 && git add $1 && git commit $1; }`

First it will pop open up a diff, when you close it, it will allow you enter a commit message.

usage example:

`gdiffy config/database.yml`

or

`gdiffy .`

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a GUI environment. You can launch `"git gui"` from the console.. 
This would launch a window, where the left pane would contain the list of changed files. Selecting any of them, shows you the diff. 
You can add files by clicking on the icon to the left of the file name and later commit it from the same window.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Note: diff + commit would not work because you have not *added* anything to the index.

As commented, [`git add -i` or `git add -p` (`--patch`)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add--i) will give you a diff view, with the possibility to add or skip each diff hunk.
Then you can commit the modified index.

Comment: True without "add" it does not work! i added the "add" now! its just a fast hack!